# Can't resolve 'crypto' in './node_modules/sjcl' while using SJCL in Angular 7

Tags: angular, cryptography, sjcl

I want to encrypt data at clients side, so I found SJCL npm.

Gone through their documentation. However, less documentation provided by SJCL contributors, can't implement that in Angular

I have tried the following.

I installed the package

1. npm install --save sjcl

   after that I tried installing type definitions also
2. npm install --save sjcl @types/sjcl

here is my package.json

```
{

"name": "project-name",

"version": "0.0.0",


  "scripts": {

    "ng": "ng",

    "start": "ng serve",

    "build": "ng build",

    "test": "ng test",

    "lint": "ng lint",

    "e2e": "ng e2e"

  },

  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/cdk": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",

    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",

    "@types/sjcl": "^1.0.28",

    "angular-filepond": "^1.0.5",

    "core-js": "^2.5.4",

    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",

    "sjcl": "^1.0.8",

    "tslib": "^1.9.0",

    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",

    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.2",

    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",

    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",

    "@schematics/angular": "~7.1.0",

    "@types/echarts": "^4.1.3",

    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",

    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",

    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",

    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",

    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",

    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",

    "karma": "~3.1.1",

    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",

    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",

    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",

    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",

    "protractor": "~5.4.0",

    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",

    "tslint": "~5.11.0",

    "typescript": "~3.1.6"

  }
}
```

Also I have done this

```
import * as sjcl from 'sjcl';
```

in one of my component.

Moreover, I have gone through this link
[Using SJCL library in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029690/using-sjcl-library-in-angular2)

When I run angular app, I am getting

```
** WARNING in ./node_modules/sjcl/sjcl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in './node_modules/sjcl'**


**Note starts:**

used sjcl.encrypt("password", "data")
but after console.log(sjcl.encrypt("password", "data"))
it shows undefined

**Note ends:**
```

May be my ***note*** is not that perfect or I defined it wrong. How to use SJCL to encrypt data without this warning?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, after some research I found that it was node related warning. With Angular you need to modify the file:

> node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js

at the end of the file I changed

> node: false,

into

> node: {crypto: true, stream: true},

Comment: Bravo to see some answers here... however, i have not implemented your code yet

Answer (score 1):

I have used sjcl library for my react application.
But the process remains the same.

```
import sjcl from 'sjcl';
```

Now you can use sjcl.encrypt() function.
If you are looking for some example of AES encryption you can see my detailed answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60504619/6453913

You can also use the tradional commonJs require method too.

Comment: I am not looking for react import as i have angular code with me. Also, Angular is moving so fast with the versioning and introduced IVY in the upgraded versioning... will go for angular in upcoming projects... katar supporter of angular :-)

Comment: React/ Angular or anything depends upon use cases.
Moreover I just tested it with angular its working as expected.